# Multiple procs execution using row count in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a proc in which I need to execute 4 different query based on the condition if the result from 1st query is 0 then it should execute the 2nd query and so on
I am using the @@RowCount to find the row count and then passing the value. Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE FetchingValues @StartLocation Varchar(200),@EndLocation Varchar(200)

AS

DECLARE
       @Count NUMERIC

BEGIN 
 if @@ROWCOUNT=0
 BEGIN
            select DISTINCT TOP 1 t1.Train_No,Max(t1.Distance) as TotalDistance,0 as Waiting_Time
            from Rail t1
            where t1.Source_Station_Name Like @StartLocation+'%'
            and t1.Destination_Station_Name Like @EndLocation+'%'
            GROUP BY t1.Train_No
            Order BY TotalDistance ASC
    SET @Count= (SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
END
ELSE if @Count <> 1
BEGIN
EXEC Connection1 @StartLocation,@EndLocation
SET @Count=(SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
END
ELSE if @Count <> 1 
BEGIN
EXEC Connection2 @StartLocation,@EndLocation
SET @Count=(SELECT @@ROWCOUNT)
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select DISTINCT TOP 1 (t1.Train_No+','+ t2.Train_No+','+t3.Train_No+','+t4.Train_No) as TrainSeq,
Max(t1.Distance)+Max(t2.Distance)+Max(t3.Distance)+Max(t4.Distance)as TotalDistance
from Rail t1
join Rail t2 on (t2.Source_Station_Name=t1.Destination_Station_Name)
Join Rail t3 on (t3.Source_Station_Name=t2.Destination_Station_Name)
Join Rail t4 on (t4.Source_Station_Name=t3.Destination_Station_Name)
where t1.Source_Station_Name Like @StartLocation+'%'
and t2.Destination_Station_Name Like @EndLocation+'%'
Group by t1.Train_No,T2.Train_No,t3.Train_No,t4.Train_No
ORDER BY TotalDistance ASC
END
```

I want to execute the query by passing 2 values then I should check through all the queries and should get the output

Answer (score 0):

If you need to suppress empty resultsets then there is only one way - `insert exec` into temp table and check whethere there is anything or not. If there are records - no need to run next queries, just select from #.

```
BEGIN 
  select DISTINCT TOP 1 t1.Train_No,Max(t1.Distance) as TotalDistance,0 as Waiting_Time
  into #t -- <<<<<<
  from Rail t1
  where t1.Source_Station_Name Like @StartLocation+'%'
    and t1.Destination_Station_Name Like @EndLocation+'%'
  GROUP BY t1.Train_No

if not exists(select 1 from #t)
BEGIN
  insert #t
  EXEC Connection1 @StartLocation,@EndLocation
END

if not exists(select 1 from #t)
BEGIN
  insert #t
  EXEC Connection2 @StartLocation,@EndLocation
END

  if not exists(select 1 from #t)
  ...

  /* finally */
  select * from #t
  Order BY TotalDistance ASC
END
```

Comment: can you elaborate it more ? I didn't get you or you can show me how to execute it

Comment: when I execute it and pass the values the exec stops at Connection1 but it should go to connection2

Comment: I guess this means that connection1 returned something.